# How to fix an "no instance of constructor matches argument list" error in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ right now and I am writing a program that utilizes member initializer list. Here is the code that I am working with:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct ClockOfTheLongNow {
    ClockOfTheLongNow() { 
        year = 2019;
    }
    void add_year() {
        year++;
    }
    bool set_year(int new_year) { 
        if (new_year < 2019) return false;
        year = new_year;
        return true;
    }
    int get_year() const { 
        return year;
    }
private:
    int year;
};

struct Avout{
    Avout(const char* name, long year_of_apert) : name{ name }, apert{ year_of_apert } {

    }
    void announce() const {
        printf("My name is %s and my next apert is %d.\n", name, apert.get_year());
    }
    const char* name;
    ClockOfTheLongNow apert;
};

int main() {
    Avout raz{ "Eramas", 3010 }; 
    Avout jad{ "Jad", 4000 };
    raz.announce();
    jad.announce();
}
```

The error that I am getting is coming from this line here where it says apert{ year_of_apert }:

```
Avout(const char* name, long year_of_apert) : name{ name }, apert{ year_of_apert } {
```

The error that I am getting back is this:

```
no instance of constructor "ClockOfTheLongNow::ClockOfTheLongNow" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (long)
```

I have already tried to look up solutions to the problem but, so far, have had no luck. The expected output is supposed to be this:

```
My name is Erasmas and my next apert is 3010.
My name is Jad and my next apert is 4000.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClockOfTheLongNow` does not have a constructor that takes a `long` (or any other kind of value) as input, but you are trying to construct the `apert` member by passing `year_of_apert` to its constructor.

You need to add a [*converting constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) to `ClockOfTheLongNow`, eg:

```cpp
struct ClockOfTheLongNow {
    ClockOfTheLongNow() { // <-- default constructor
        year = 2019;
    }

    ClockOfTheLongNow(int theYear) { // <-- add a converting constructor
        year = theYear;
    }

    ...
private:
    int year;
};
```

Alternatively, you can change your existing [*default constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) to give it a default parameter value so it can act as a *converting constructor* as well, eg:

```cpp
struct ClockOfTheLongNow {
    ClockOfTheLongNow(int theYear = 2019) { // <-- default + converting constructor
        year = theYear;
    }
    ...
private:
    int year;
};
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed the error. However now I am getting compiler errors when I try to compile the program in g++.

Comment: Then you have other mistakes in your code. What are the actual error messages? You may need to post a new question about that.

Comment: Never mind I managed to fix the compile errors on my own. Everything is working as it should now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you there is no constructor present for the type you are giving it in the parameters.

You give a type `long` parameter to the `Avout` constructor, which you then initialize in the `apert` variable, which is of the type `ClockOfTheLongNow`.

In other words, you have to create a new constructor for your clock struct which would look something like this:

```
ClockOfTheLongNow(long parameterYear) { 
    year = parameterYear;
}
```